# RSA encryption library or Classes

Tags: iphone, encryption, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I want to implement RSA encrytion/decryption in my App.I googled around the net to find any Library or Classes which perform the RSA encryption/decryption algorithm,but was not able to find any suitable link.I know i can use the SecKeyGeneratePair provided by Apple to generate the private public key pair.But it is a necessity for me to use the RSA algorithm as i want to implement it over client-server network.So the Algorithm needs to common amongst the parties.

Please provide some valuable info.

Thanks

Aditya

Comment: can you please post your code how did you generated RSA encryption using SecKeyEncrypt. I am stuck in that. Please help if possible.

Comment: HI can you please guide me how you have implemented RSA using  SecKeyDecrypt & SecKeyEncrypt function?? Please help me and share your code if possible. Thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't that what `SecKeyEncrypt` and `SecKeyDecrypt` functions do?

The functions [SecKeyEncrypt](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecKeyEncrypt) and [SecKeyDecrypt](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecKeyDecrypt) uses the RSA keys you got from `SecKeyGeneratePair`.